# If every fuction $f:A \mapsto B$ with $A\subseteq B, f(A)=B$ is not injective(1-1) then $A\supset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we prove this statement:

If for every fuction $f:A \mapsto B$  with $A\subseteq B, f(A)=B$  is not injective(1-1) then $A\supset B$

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then the identity function is injective. So the whole question is moot.

Comment: If $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(0,2)$ then why cannot find a non injective function f?

Comment: Again, I am pretty sure the identity function is injective. Check your math.

Comment: @Asaf: You're right that the identity function is non-injective, but in that case, we wouldn't necessarily have $f(A)=B.$

Comment: You are correct .I should not write ''for every function'' .

Comment: Cameron Bruie :  We would if A=B

Comment: @mikemoke: You're correct. I've just updated my comment. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've either mis-stated the result or that the result given to you was mis-stated. Instead, it seems that it should be stated in one of the two following forms:

1. If $A\supseteq B,$ and for every surjection $f:A\to B$ we have that $f$ is non-injective, then $A\supset B.$
2. If $A\subseteq B,$ and for every surjection $f:A\to B$ we have that $f$ is non-injective, then $A\subset B.$

The upshot, here, is that the hypotheses above state that there is no bijection $A\to B.$ Consequently, we can't have $A=B$ (for if that were true, then the identity function would contradict the hypotheses), so $A\supseteq B$ would imply that $A\supset B,$ and $A\subseteq B$ would imply that $A\subset B.$

---

Noting that it is impossible for $A\subseteq B$ and $A\supset B$ to be simultaneously true, then in order for the implication to be true, we would have to prove that the hypotheses are necessarily false. However, this will not be possible. Consider $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}.$ Note that $A\subseteq B,$ and that every surjection $f:A\to B$ is an injection, because there *aren't* any surjections $f:A\to B$. However, it certainly isn't true that $A\supset B.$

Comment: So the statement i made is a contradiction?

Comment: That's fair to say. I've updated my answer to show what the statement might have been intended to say.

Comment: So the initial problem was to prove that there exists an injective
$f:A \mapsto B$  for every $A\subseteq B, f(A)=B$.
I tried to prove using  contradiction and this is how the question arise.

Comment: That initial problem (as stated) doesn't make sense to me. Can you state it exactly as given?

Comment: We are given $h:A\rightarrow C , g:B\rightarrow C $
Both are 1-1 and onto .  Also $B\subseteq K\subseteq A$
Prove that there exists injective and onto $\mu :K\rightarrow C$ .

Comment: We can use g to show that there exists μ  that is onto .
We use $μ(h^{-1}(x)) :K\rightarrow A$ for 1-1.
Let $f(x)=μ(h^{-1}(x))$ and you need to prove the statement i made in the third comment.

Comment: Okay, that makes much more sense. I don't have time to answer it right now, though. I recommend that you put the initial problem in a new question, together with your reasoning so far, and ask how to get the rest of the way. With more context and effort shown by you, it is more likely to be well-received and get an answer.

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) for an idea how you might proceed.